# MySQL: Compute difference of two timestamps in different table rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep on looking around StackOverflow for a similar question but it seems that I can't find one. I would like to know the difference between timestamps in different rows grouped by employee ID.

Time Logs table:

```
id        timestamp             log_type
 1    2019-06-19 12:34:50        log_in
 2    2019-06-19 13:12:46       start_break 
 3    2019-06-19 13:13:56        end_break
 4    2019-06-19 17:23:40       start_break
 5    2019-06-19 17:44:36        end_break
 6    2019-06-19 19:00:04       start_break
 7    2019-06-19 19:03:17         end_break
 8    2019-06-19 20:05:54        log_out
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to calculate all duration of breaks. In this case, 1st break (id #2 and #3) is 1 minute and 10 seconds, 2nd break (id #4 and #5) is 20 minutes and 56 seconds, 3rd break (id #6 and #7) is 3 minutes and 13 seconds thus with the total of 25 minutes and 19 seconds.

Thanks for helping out! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9b8448d17ed363b6bbba510d051448d2)**

```
select SEC_TO_TIME(sum(diff)) as result from
(
select  
timestampdiff(second,min(case when log_tpe='start_break' then timestamps end) ,
min(case when log_tpe='end_break' then timestamps end)) as diff
from t
group by date(timestamps),hour(timestamps)
)A
```

OUTPUT:

```
result
00:25:19
```

Comment: Your last edit returned 25 minutes and 19 seconds. Your first answer worked though. May I know the reason for the change?

Comment: @Ronald actually your result also should 25 because you can see the difference of minutes between 4 & 5 is 21 (44-23)

Comment: yeah. wrong calculation on my end. But it seems your first two answers were correct, why change it? :)

Comment: @Ronald, this is more appropriate according to your requirement - first one only give you value in seconds, as you need minutes and seconds so I change it SEC_TO_TIME() which'll give you value as time format

Comment: actually, your first answer gave minutes (e.g 25.3167). thanks for extending your help on making it to the format that I gave. Will have this as accepted answer.